# How to erase directories that contain less than a certain number of files

Tags: shell-script, find

How can I find and delete subdirectories that contain less than 100 files (or 200 files)?

I have found and used the following command, but don't know how to delete the listed subdirectories. (I have over 1000 of such folders and subdirectories, can't do it by hand).

```
find . -maxdepth 5 -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{} '; ls '{}' | wc -l" \; | awk '$NF<=10'
```

thank you!

Comment: What if a directory contains no files but does contain more than 200 subdirectories? Should that be removed? How about links? Do they count as files? What if a directory contains few files but has a subdirectory with many? Should it be kept? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. The command you're using will fail on dile names with whitespace and will also delete parent directories whose children you might want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Below I have included the answer to your question, however I would like to stress that you need to exercise extreme caution with this command. The output of your original `awk` is being piped into `rm -rf`, this means that this command is forcibly removing all the folders listed.

Make sure that you are very careful as to where you run this because, if run in most places, this could cause massive problems or irreparable damage to the system.

---

```
find . -maxdepth 5 -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{} '; ls '{}' | wc -l" \; -print0 | awk '$NF<=10' | xargs rm -rf
```

The output of your original command is being piped into `xarge rm -rf`, `xargs` is converting the original output into arguments for another program, in this case, `rm`.

Excerpt from the manpage for `rm` for the two switches being used:

```
       -f, --force
          ignore nonexistent files, never prompt

       -r, -R, --recursive
          remove directories and their contents recursively
```

Piping directly into `rm` wouldn't work as it does not expect to receive file or folder names in that format.

Comment: @countermode there are indeed problems with this answer since it won't work as expected for file names with spaces in them, but the filtering is being done. Note the `awk '$NF<=10'`.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for pointing that out, I will add that now.

Comment: Sorry for that, I experimented with the command but removed the awk part in order to see the full output.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
for d (**/*(Nod/))
  ()(($#)) $d/*(ND.Y100[100]) ||
  ()(($#)) $d/*(ND/Y1) ||
  rm -rf -- $d
```

Would delete the non-hidden directories that do not contain 100 regular files or more and do not contain subdirectories. That's processed depth-first so directories get a chance to be deleted if they have subdirectories that are to be deleted themselves.

- `**/` matches any level of subdirectories
- `(Nod/)` / `(NDoN.[100])` / `(ND/Y1)`: glob qualifiers to further qualify the glob based on other criteria:

  - `N`: nullglob: don't treat it as a fatal error if there's no match, but let the glob expand to nothing instead.
  - `D`: dotglob: don't ignore hidden (`D`ot) files.
  - `od`: `o`rder `d`epth first (leaves before the branch they're on)
  - `oN`: do `N`ot bother `o`rdering the list
  - `/`: restrict to files of type *directory*
  - `.`: restrict to files of type *regular*. Change to `^/` to consider files of any type except *directory* instead.
  - `Y1`/`Y100`: stop searching after 1/100 match(es) and don't even bother sorting
  - `[100]`: selects the 100<sup>th</sup> match only; so `Y100[100]` will make the glob result in one file if there are 100 or more, or none otherwise in a more efficient way than with `[100]` alone which would find all matches, sort the list and select the 100<sup>th</sup>.
- `(){body} args`: runs an anonymous function with `args` as arguments.
- `(($#))` as the body of the anonymous function is an arithmetic expression that returns true if the expression evaluates to a number other than 0. So here if `$#`, the number of arguments to the anonymous function is non-zero.

Answer (score -1):

*Below script is dirty yet working solution.*

**Run this script on testing env before applying on working computer as it will delete the contents**

```
cd desired_directory
for i in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep "/"`
do
   cd $i;
   j=`echo \`ls -l | wc -l\` | bc`
   [ $j -lt "100" ] && echo "Lesser than 100 files/directories in $i"
   cd ../
done
```

Here, you have to replace the `echo` statement with either `rm -rf` or `mv`.

Comment: 1) not sure about cd .., you'd rather use `(cd $i, ... )` inside for loop. 2) OP say less, replace `-gt` by `-lt`